# Group by and Order by in the same select

Tags: sql, oracle

i've this query:

```
  SELECT MODELLI.MOD_DESC, 
         COUNT(MOD_DESC)
    FROM VEGA.DISTRIB AS DISTRIB, 
         VEGA.MODELLI AS MODELLI
   WHERE DISTRIB.DIS_FLAG = 'M' 
     AND DISTRIB.DIS_MOD = MODELLI.MOD_COD
   GROUP BY MODELLI.MOD_DESC
```

But i want to have the ORDER BY on MODELLI.MOD_DESC too.

How i can do this?

Thanks.

Comment: after group by order by mod_desc doesnt work????/?

Comment: Nope. Don't work. It's a problem of the oracle db?

Comment: Could you decide what DB do you have? Oracle or MySQL?

Comment: Oracle, sorry. Bad Tag

Comment: "*Don't work*" is not an acceptable error description. Please post the **full** error message you get.

Comment: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: [Microsoft] [ODBC driver for Oracle] [Oracle] ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

Comment: After some edit i get this: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: [Microsoft] [ODBC driver for Oracle] [Oracle] ORA-00933: SQL command completed incorrectly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try,

```
SELECT MODELLI.MOD_DESC, COUNT(MODELLI.MOD_DESC)
FROM VEGA.DISTRIB DISTRIB, VEGA.MODELLI MODELLI
WHERE DISTRIB.DIS_FLAG = 'M' AND DISTRIB.DIS_MOD = MODELLI.MOD_COD
GROUP BY MODELLI.MOD_DESC ORDER BY MODELLI.MOD_DESC
```

It will work as OP suggested..

Try this now..

Comment: I get an error. I'm working on an Oracle DB

Comment: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: [Microsoft] [ODBC driver for Oracle] [Oracle] ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

Comment: Editted the above code... Try now

Comment: emh... but it's the same code. What u have editted?

Comment: COUNT(MOD_DESC) Changed to COUNT(MODELLI.MOD_DESC)

Comment: Don't work. System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: [Microsoft] [ODBC driver for Oracle] [Oracle] ORA-00933: SQL command completed incorrectly

Comment: Is this the complete query...????   When you use group by and an aggregate function together, you need to put all the attributes that are not a part of the aggregate function, in the group by clause.

Comment: Yes, my query is complete.

Comment: As Dba suggested, try removing AS from my editted post.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ORDER BY` clause just after the `GROUP BY` clause like,

```
SELECT MODELLI.MOD_DESC, 
       COUNT(MOD_DESC)
FROM   VEGA.DISTRIB DISTRIB, 
       VEGA.MODELLI MODELLI
WHERE  DISTRIB.DIS_FLAG = 'M' 
AND    DISTRIB.DIS_MOD = MODELLI.MOD_COD
GROUP BY MODELLI.MOD_DESC
ORDER BY MODELLI.MOD_DESC;
```

Comment: I get an error. I'm working on an Oracle DB

Comment: @Alist3r, Show us your error.

Comment: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: [Microsoft] [ODBC driver for Oracle] [Oracle] ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

Comment: @Alist3r, Please try with my updated answer. I've removed the `AS` from line 2 and 3.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT MODELLI.MOD_DESC, COUNT(MOD_DESC)
FROM VEGA.DISTRIB AS DISTRIB, VEGA.MODELLI AS MODELLI
WHERE DISTRIB.DIS_FLAG = 'M' AND DISTRIB.DIS_MOD = MODELLI.MOD_COD
GROUP BY MODELLI.MOD_DESC
order by MODELLI.MOD_DESC ASC
```

Comment: I get an error. I'm working on an Oracle DB